# How to ask a question according to the phrase in bold?

Tags: difference, prepositions, questions

He is ***from America***.    The question should be : Where is he ***from***?

He is ***in the classroom***.   The question should be: Where is he?

I don't figure out : The sentence constituent of the phrases in these two sentence are the same, but why the questions are so different, why the first question should have the preposition"from" ? So "Where" refers to a preposition phrase or a noun phrase?

Answer (score 1):

> Where is he from?

could be paraphrased as

> Where he *comes* from? Where *was* he born?

Note that what we mean here is not "where is he *now*" but "where *was* he some time ago?" So we need this 'from' to indicate that we're asking not about the person's present location.

On the other hand, in

> Where is he?

we are asking where is the person now, at this moment: it is likely that the asker is not aware that the person is **in** some room: he may well be **on** the roof of the school, or **at** the parking lot talking with a friend. Thus we limit ourselves to the bare form of question, without a preposition.